# What is the 'Sound Settings' program's name in Ubuntu

Tags: sound, xubuntu, bluetooth, indicator-sound

I use Xubuntu. 
Recently I removed all Ubuntu/Unity related packages in the hope to have a more responsive and less cluttered system.

Before I removed Ubuntu/Unity packages following using [this command](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexfce).

After the removing of the packages the program thats starts when selecting 'Sound Settings...' is a different one than it was before when Unity was installed.

[image: Panel > Sound Indicator > Sound Settings...]

As I have a bluetooth speaker I connect to I would like to have the 'old' sound settings program back. The latter enabled me to select the bluetooth speaker as output.

I did install sudo apt-get install `gnome-control-center` and the sound menu became the old one again. Good but once I've connected my bluetooth speakers via the bluetooth indicator in the panel there is still no speaker to select as output.

What package do I need to install?

Comment: XFCE uses it's own Sound Settings, the picture you're showing is the Sound Indicator. And it's available as part of the xfce extras/goodies package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that Sound Settings is a part of gnome-control-center. Whenever I open sound settings and run `killall gnome-control-center` (This command will kill the process requested), it closes my Sound Settings.

Comment: If I install 'gnome-control-center' all gnome dependencies will be installed again, correct?

Comment: I actually am not too sure. Try this command in terminal: `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center` and look at the list of packages to be installed. I'm not too sure what all will be installed. Can you post what terminal tells you?

Comment: You can *check* what will be installed when you issue the command on the *Terminal*

Comment: I did install `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center` and all was good again :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I was a bit fast. The _gnome-control-center_ brings back the sound settings but the speaker is not shown once connected via bluetooth.

Answer (score 27):

In GNOME audio settings are controlled by the GNOME Control Center

```
gnome-control-center sound
```

GNOME is not installed by default in Xubuntu. You can access audio settings by installing the package [**pavucontrol**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/pavucontrol) for controlling sound settings without GNOME dependencies:

[image]

Comment: I did install this program but I still had issues finding the bluetooth speaker. The other answer got me back to my initial state.

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you don't mind the many dependencies you will need in addition then of course you can install GNOME applications or even GNOME on top of XFCE. ;)

Comment: +1 for `gnome-control-center sound`, the command to directly open the Gnome Sound Settings window. Works on Fedora as well.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what program you were using before, but you can easily find out what what programs are readily available to you to this sort of thing type `apropos mixer` or `apropos mix` at the command line. In my case it pops up a list of two:

- alsamixer
- amixer

The first one, alsamixer, is a mixer that works from the console and offers a lot of functionality. Check the man page `man alsamixer` to  figure out the key bindings.

Another option is to search for 'mixer' in available packages, but that will only work if the mixer has a package of its own, not packaged with other desktop tools:
`apt-cache search mixer | grep mixer -i --color`

Maybe you are able to find out which mixer you were using by browsing through the /var/log/dpkg.log, `grep -i mix /var/log/dpkg.log*`

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble with opening the settings, i.e, I was unable to fix or update anything and pulseaudio was already running and therefore won't open.

I solved it by:

```bash
sudo apt install pavucontrol
pavucontrol
```